# If two cells match return value from third

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I have two tabs on a spreadsheet (Current and Previous) and I have a third tab (Changes) to show the differences between the two for certain columns (H) with a Current column and a Previous column in the Changes tab. I have an unique identifier in both tabs in column A and I have copied this to column A in the Changes tab. I am trying an Index and Match formula but it is not working. Formula I have to firstly return the value from the Current tab is =INDEX(Current!H:H,MATCH(Current!A:A,Changes!A:A,0)) and the formula to return the value from the Previous tab is (Previous!H:H,MATCH(Previous!A:A,Changes!A:A,0)). Any ideas please.

Comment: You totally lost me in the middle of the explanation. So you were not able to get the values from Current and Previous? Or you could get the values but not the difference? I assume it's the first. Have you tried using OFFSET instead of INDEX? If you break down your formula, i.e. separate the MATCH in one column and the INDEX/OFFSET in another, you should be able to spot where the problem comes from.

Comment: I believe the match should be `MATCH(Changest!A1,Current!A:A,0)` instead (assuming you are using the formula somewhere on row 1 in Changes).

Comment: Thank you and @Jerry I have switched the formula around as per Jerry's note and this seems to work. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need Index/Match for this. A normal VLOOKUP should do the job because your unique IDs are all in column A. The formula below will will return TRUE if both values are equal, FALSE if they are not, and ERR if one of them can't be found in either sheet. Use this formula in the Changes sheet.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2,Current!$A$2:$H$10000,8,FALSE)=VLOOKUP($A2,Previous!$A$2:$H$10000,8,FALSE),"ERR")
```

I have presumed that your sheet will have less than 10,000 rows. You might increase the number or decrease it. I recommend the use of named ranges.

Comment: thank you for this but I need to actually show the values of each column from the Current and Previous tab so I can see specifically what has changed.

Comment: Each of the two VLOOKUP functions in the formula returns one of the values. Put them into separate cells and you got precisely what you are asking. Do you need help with splitting the formula?

Comment: Hi @variatus I actually used the formula that Jerry said above which works (not sure if you can see that). Thank you for your reply though.